# DependencyProperty and WPF Designer

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

```
class MyLine : Shape {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty X11Property;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty X22Property;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Y11Property;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Y22Property;

    static MyLine() {
        X11Property = DependencyProperty.Register("X11", typeof(double), typeof(MyLine), new UIPropertyMetadata(double.NaN));
        X22Property = DependencyProperty.Register("X22", typeof(double), typeof(MyLine), new UIPropertyMetadata(double.NaN));
        Y11Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Y11", typeof(double), typeof(MyLine), new UIPropertyMetadata(double.NaN));
        Y22Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Y22", typeof(double), typeof(MyLine), new UIPropertyMetadata(double.NaN));
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))]
    public double X11 { get { return (double)GetValue(X11Property); } set { SetValue(X11Property, value); } }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))]
    public double X22 { get { return (double)GetValue(X22Property); } set { SetValue(X22Property, value); } }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))]
    public double Y11 { get { return (double)GetValue(Y11Property); } set { SetValue(Y11Property, value); } }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))]
    public double Y22 { get { return (double)GetValue(Y22Property); } set { SetValue(Y22Property, value); } }

    protected override System.Windows.Media.Geometry DefiningGeometry {
        get {
            var geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();

            // Add line
            geometryGroup.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(X11, Y11), new Point(X22, Y22)));
            return geometryGroup;
        }
    }
}
```

Why when I update the "myLine" coordinates in WPF designer(VS 2010), it does not update it automatically(live)?

When using default "Line" WPF objects, they are automatically updated when the XAML code is changed(edited) in XAML/Design view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since these properties affect rendering, you should specify it in the metadata:

```
X11Property = DependencyProperty.Register("X11", typeof(double), typeof(DirectionLine), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double.NaN, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

I'm not sure it will be enough for the designer to take it into account, but it's worth a try...